# How to focus on browser window with AHK hotkeys?

Tags: firefox, autohotkey

Goal's to refresh and focus onto an existing Mozilla Firefox page (away from any current focus); achieved former, but not latter:

```
^!s::ControlSend,,{F5},ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
    WinActivate, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
return
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have more than one command executed by a hotkey, put the first line beneath the hotkey definition and make the last line a return:

```
^!s::
    ControlSend,,{F5},ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
    WinActivate, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro